# Fetching childs id from parent id in javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hello I am developing a jQuery mobile app and Here is the situation

```
<script>
    function showPanel(info) {

        alert(info.id);
        alert($(info).next()[0].id);

    }
</script>

<div data-role="footer" id="footer_button" onclick="showPanel(this);">

        <h4 style="text-align: center;">Open toolbar</h4>

</div>

<div id="footerhigher1">

    <div id="footerinner1"></div>

</div>
```

Now in this code `onclick` event of the first div I am passing `this` from which I am extracting the id of the first `div` and by the **next()** mothod of jQuery I am fetching the ID of the next div. Now I also want to get the id of the child whose ID is **footerinner1** So how can I take that ID
I have multiple combination like these in single page

more Explicit View

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Page Title</h1>

            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>Page content goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="footer" id="footer_button1">
                 <h4 style="text-align: center;">Open toolbar</h4>

            </div>
            <!-- ... -->
            <div id="footerhigher1" class="higher">
                <div id="footerinner-1-1" class="inner"></div>
                <div id="footerinner-1-2" class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Page Title</h1>

            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>Page content goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="footer" id="footer_button2">
                 <h4 style="text-align: center;">Open toolbar</h4>

            </div>
            <!-- ... -->
            <div id="footerhigher2" class="higher">
                <div id="footerinner-2-1" class="inner"></div>
                <div id="footerinner-2-2" class="inner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Page Title</h1>

            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>Page content goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="footer" id="footer_button3">
                 <h4 style="text-align: center;">Open toolbar</h4>

            </div>
            <!-- ... -->
            <div id="footerhigher3" class="higher">
                <div id="footerinner-3-1" class="inner"></div>
            </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `$(info).next().children()[0].id` -- but this is a bit of a sloppy approach on the whole.

Comment: please elaborate question. what you want ? how would be the end result?

Comment: @ahren as your are saying "sloppy approach on the whole" can you please provide me some explaination

Comment: Assign classes to the footer divs, like `higher` and `inner`. Makes it easier to find the preferred div. Also you may want to use jquery-style event handlers instead of the onclick inside the html tag.

Comment: `^` exactly what Imperative said.

Comment: @Ravi I also want to fetch the childs div id under the <div id="footerhigher1"></div>...... Ihave many conbination in like these in a single page thats why

Comment: @Imperative "use jquery-style event handlers instead of the onclick inside the html tag" I first thinked of this approach only but how can I pass the this object of the element which is clicked. Actuallty for using jQuery style handlers you need to know the class or id or anything but here the no of divs are dynamic.

Please tell me if you can suggest a better solution through jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked how to do it with jquery-style event handling:

```
$('#footer_button').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    alert($this.attr('id');
    // traversing the dom etc.
});
```

Also updated html:

```
<div data-role="footer" id="footer_button">
    <h4 style="text-align: center;">Open toolbar</h4>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
<div id="footerhigher1" class="higher">
    <div id="footerinner1" class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is what I am saying

$('#footer_button') you are using footer_button explicitly. In my code there are 100 divs like these and that too vary on every refresh. How can I do it without usuing this footer_button

Comment: Show a more explicit code example, please. I can't imagine what your code looks like.

Comment: have you got something out of it

Comment: Please explain this line     $('.higher', $page).toggle();

Comment: It selects all elements of class `higher` inside the `$page` element and applys the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function to the selected elements. You could write the selector in many ways, but i prefer this one because of it's simplicity. Another way, maybe more clear to understand: `$page.find('.higher').toggle();`

Answer (score 0):

May this work :

```
alert($(info).next().children().eq[0].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 alert($(info).next().children('div').attr('id'));
```